# Difficulty invoking methods of subclass from Array of both Superclass and subclass objects

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, instanceof

The aim is to be able to read data from a textfile containing information pertaining to stocklevels into an object and then manipulating that object in various ways
fields in the textfile are seperated by "#". The textfile either has 3 fields on a line or 5 fields on a line.
line with 3 fields go into the constructor of my superclass
line with 5 fields go read into the subclass

The superclass is called StockItem and the subclass is called StockItemFood, it extends StockItem(the superclass).

Below is my code, found in a seperate 'Manager' class which reads from the textfile into an array of StockItem objects. simple enough.

```
public void readFromText() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    String [] temp;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("stocklist.txt"));
    String line = br.readLine();

    while(line!=null){
        temp=line.split("#");

        if (temp.length==3){
            s[counter]=new StockItem(temp[0], (double) Integer.parseInt(temp[1]), temp[3]);
        }else if (temp.length==5){
            s[counter]=new StockItemFood(temp[0], (double) Integer.parseInt(temp[1]), temp[2], (double) Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), (double) Integer.parseInt(temp[4]));
        }
    }

    counter++;
    br.close();
}
```

In the below method i am trying to return a String that will be concatinated with the return of a method from the Superclass and a return from a method in the subclass. I cannot however see my subclass methods when i type s[y]. as seen below.

```
public String getOrderingList(){ 
    String toOrder="";

    for(int y = 0; y < s.length; y++){
        toOrder+=s[y].getDescription() + s[y].//getOrderAmount() <-subclass method          
        }
    }

    return toOrderl
}
```

Below is the code for my subclass:

```
public class StockItemFood extends StockItem {

private double min,max; //3.2

public StockItemFood(String description, double quantity, String units,double min, double max) { //3.3
    super(description, quantity, units);
    this.min = min;
    this.max=max;
}

public boolean mustOrder(){ //3.4
    boolean b;

    if(getQuantity()<min){
        b=true;
    } else {
        b=false;
    }
    return b;
}

public double getOrderAmount(){ //3.5
    double amount = max-getQuantity();
    return amount;
}
```

}

I thought of maybe using instanceof but i am not entirely sure of the syntax required and i've also read several posts where it was adviced to avoid instanceof.

Any help would be much appreciated.
- Shaun

Comment: What is `s`? Its unclear.

Comment: See the answer I have provided for your example. Yes instanceOf should not be used if there is a workaround. It usually means design smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abstract class StockItem{

     protected abstract double getOrderAmount();


     public String getOrderingList(){
          String result = method(); //can invoke it
     }
}

class StockItemFood extends StockItem{
   @Override
   protected double getOrderAmount(){
      //return the value
   }
}
```

[Abstract keyword in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

I don't know if I have completely understood your question. But I will try to answer it. Create method `getOrderAmount()` as `abstract` in your base class.

If every `StockItem` in your design is going to have a order amount then you should define it as abstract method in your class `StockItem`.

> i've also read several posts where it was adviced to avoid
>   instanceof.

Yes that is true, you should avoid using instanceof as it means you don't have proper design for your code.

Answer (score 0):

still unclear about your explanation, the solution given is based on a feeble understanding, Explain further by editing your question and maybe a better solution will be provided then.

assuming `s` is an array of type SuperClass

```
String toOrder = "";
for(int y=0;y<s.length;y++){
  toOrder+=s[y].superClassMethod();

  if(s[y] instanceof subclass) {
    toOrder+= ( (SubClassName)s[y]).subClassMethod();
  }
}
```

will work for you

Comment: @NarendraPathai : OP is not sure on how to use instanceof